# Using "Unnecessary Node Check", ESRI's Data Reviewer Extension

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-reviewer

Have been working with the ESRI's Data Reviewer Extension to identify unnecessary nodes.  The  "Unnecessary Nodes Check Properties" dialog implies that the result return (1) a node (if topology exists) or (2) a polyline (info topology exists).  I can't seem to get the dialog to return nodes only polylines and I have a topology built.  Any suggestions? [image]

Comment: It should return a point, coincident with an endpoint shared between two lines whose attributes do not significantly differ (pseudo node) or a suspect polyline to check. If you're not highlighting errors check your fields to ensure OBJECTID and SHAPE_LENGTH aren't included as significant fields. Nodes as a feature type went out with ArcInfo coverages. What difficulty are you having? is it not working or not highlighting errors?

Comment: Michael - thanks for the reply.  I figured out my problem. I needed to start a "Review Session."  It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the nodes rather than the polylines one must first create a geodatabase topology for the features in questions.  Then using the Data Reviewer tool bar create a "Reviewer Session" using the "Reviewer Session Manager." Simply browse to a Geodatabase (e.g. Scratch.mdb) and then click New to create session.  Once a session has been created the appropriate checks (e.g. Unnecessary Node Checks) can be set up and then run by clicking the "Feature to Validate) and then selecting "Write to Reviewer Table."

Comment: The Reviewer Session is intrinsic to the whole PLTS/Production Mapping data reviewer tool to keep track of and assist in repairing the potential errors detected by the various tools. You shouldn't even be able to access the tool without one... at least I think that's how it used to be. It's been quite a while since I reviewed this extension.

Comment: Are you saying that this solved your problem?  In any event, if you can expand on your answer, perhaps by referencing the Reviewer Session documentation, then I think you will see your answer receive more upvotes.